# iphone app size

Tags: iphone

As far as the 20 MB App limit goes for 3G connections. Which value do they use to determine the size? Is it the actual .app file or the resulting zip/ipa that's uploaded to the app store?

Does anyone have any solutions for compressing pdf's in an iphone app?

Comment: Try this solution:
[how to find correct size of an app](http://appletoolbox.com/2012/01/how-to-determine-the-true-size-of-an-app-itunes-may-be-incorrect/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zip/IPA file determines the size.

You could always have the app download the PDF's from a remote server after it is installed. That way they do not have to be included in the bundle.

Comment: thanks, is there any extra compression method i can use in my app?

Comment: The zip/ipa file is already compressed.  Finding any other compression method that may help with your particular content data is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

It is the resulting zip which must be under 20 mb.

As for compressing PDFs, unless you are generating them in your app (in which case the submission size limit wouldn't be an issue), any compression tool should work (an iOS specific implementation shouldn't be needed).

Answer (score 0):

If ou would compress pdf files, you need to decompress them before opening.

Answer (score 0):

The .app file isn't a file. It's a directory.

The size of your .zip or .ipa file is a good indication, but isn't exact, as Apple adds to and modifies the contents of the .app directory before creating the final App store .ipa file.  So I might leave a fair bit of margin below exactly 20MB.